# AS3 Custom Input Box?

Tags: flash, input, actionscript

I'm creating a pixelated-style UI and my biggest issue right now is the caret, which looks out of place as a narrow, too-tall, black line which I can't customize to be thicker, shorter, and dark grey.

The input field is myInput.text within a Console object.

I want to be able to customize or even remove the caret.
Worst case, I write my own input field using dynamic text boxes and Keyboard-Event listeners...
But that would be the worst case.

Is there an alternative?

Screenshot below.
http://puu.sh/cok71/4d3cb0f959.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain, but I don't believe this is possible. However instead of having to create an input box from scratch, maybe you could just hide the current input box? 
Continue to use all its functionality, and then just display a custom text display component that listens to the change events from the standard input box to redraw itself?
Similarly when you custom component receives focus, just pass that focus onto the input box.